# What is the correct punctuation for a repeated word?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, punctuation, commas, hyphenation

I'm creating a presentation for school and I want to title my presentation "The not so secret secret to weight loss"

My meaning is that people act as if it is a secret when in fact it is very common knowledge. Do I need a comma between the two words or a hyphen? Or is it fine the way it is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“The not-so-secret secret to weight loss.”  In this case, “not-so-secret” is the adjective describing the “secret to weight loss.” No commas.

Comment: Although not as common, another style choice is to use quotation marks around the adjectival phrase rather than hyphens: *the "not so secret" secret to weight loss.* (They serve the same purpose of making it obvious that the entire phrase is being treated as a compound.)